# How do I place the rss feed slider?

Tags: android

I have silder layout.xml in rss fragment. I do not know how to call them in fragment. I need to put some rss feed one link and get the data. Let me know if you know anyone

EnchantedViewPager

```
            <com.Tamillive.newspaper.EnchantedViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp" />
```

Rss feed layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <com.Tamillive.newspaper.EnchantedViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp" />

            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator_unselected_background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:ci_drawable="@drawable/selecteditem_dot"
                app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/nonselecteditem_dot"
                app:ci_height="6dp"
                app:ci_width="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                style="@style/listStyleNoPadding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:focusable="false" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:shimmer_duration="1000">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <include
                android:id="@+id/lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big"
                layout="@layout/include_shimmer_recipes_list_big" />





        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

RssFragment

```
 public class RssFragment extends Fragment {
    // Added argument key for URL
    private static final String ARG_URL = "url_string";
    public static final int RECIPES_LIST_SMALL = 0;
    public static final int RECIPES_LIST_BIG = 1;
    public static final int RECIPES_GRID_2_COLUMN = 2;
    public static final int RECIPES_GRID_3_COLUMN = 3;
    private RSSFeed rssFeed = null;
    private ArrayList<RSSItem> postsList;
    private RssAdapter listAdapter;

    private ViewModeUtils viewModeUtils;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    private Activity mAct;
    private RelativeLayout ll;
    private String url;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private View rootView;
    private ShimmerFrameLayout lyt_shimmer;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ll = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_refresh, container, false);
        return ll;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        lyt_shimmer = ll.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        RecyclerView listView = ll.findViewById(R.id.list);
        postsList = new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new RssAdapter(getContext(), postsList);
        listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        swipeRefreshLayout = ll.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshItems();
                initShimmerLayout();
            }





            private void initShimmerLayout() {

                View lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big = ll.findViewById(R.id.lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big);


                if (sharedPref.getRecipesViewType() == RECIPES_LIST_SMALL) {

                    lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                } else if (sharedPref.getRecipesViewType() == RECIPES_LIST_BIG) {

                    lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                } else if (sharedPref.getRecipesViewType() == RECIPES_GRID_2_COLUMN) {
        ;
                    lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                } else if (sharedPref.getRecipesViewType() == RECIPES_GRID_3_COLUMN) {

                    lyt_shimmer_recipes_list_big.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAct = getActivity();

// get URL from arguments
        url = RssFragment.this.getArguments().getString(ARG_URL);
        refreshItems();
    }

    private class RssTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
// Pass the URL string as parameter to URL class
                URL rssUrl = new URL(url);
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

                rssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
                Log.printStackTrace(e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (rssFeed != null) {
                if (rssFeed.getList().size() > 0) {
                    postsList.addAll(rssFeed.getList());
                }

                listAdapter.setHasMore(false);
                listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_LIST);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            } else {
                String message = null;
                if (!url.startsWith("http"))
                    message = "Debug info: '" + url + "' is most likely not a valid RSS url. Make sure the url entered in your configuration starts with 'http' and verify if it's valid XML using validator.w3.org/feed";
                Helper.noConnection(mAct, message);

                listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_EMPTY);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.rss_menu, menu);
        viewModeUtils = new ViewModeUtils(getContext(), getClass());
        viewModeUtils.inflateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        ThemeUtils.tintAllIcons(menu, mAct);
    }

    private void refreshItems() {
        postsList.clear();
        lyt_shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lyt_shimmer.stopShimmer();
        listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
        new RssTask().execute(


        );
    }

    private void swipeProgress(final boolean show) {
        if (!show) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(show);
            lyt_shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_shimmer.stopShimmer();
            return;
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(() -> {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(show);
            lyt_shimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_shimmer.startShimmer();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        swipeProgress(false);

        lyt_shimmer.stopShimmer();
    }







    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        viewModeUtils.handleSelection(item, new ViewModeUtils.ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void modeChanged() {
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.info:
//show information about the feed in general in a dialog
                if (rssFeed != null) {
                    String FeedTitle = (rssFeed.getTitle());
                    String FeedDescription = (rssFeed.getDescription());
//String FeedPubdate = (myRssFeed.getPubdate()); most times not present
                    String FeedLink = (rssFeed.getLink());

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mAct);

                    String titlevalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_title_value);
                    String descriptionvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_description_value);
                    String linkvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_link_value);

                    if (FeedLink.equals("")) {
                        builder.setMessage(titlevalue + ": \n" + FeedTitle +
                                "\n\n" + descriptionvalue + ": \n" + FeedDescription);
                    } else {
                        builder.setMessage(titlevalue + ": \n" + FeedTitle +
                                "\n\n" + descriptionvalue + ": \n" + FeedDescription +
                                "\n\n" + linkvalue + ": \n" + FeedLink);
                    }

                    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), null)
                            .setCancelable(true);
                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();

                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }}

    // This is the factory to instantiate the RssFragment instance with the url string as arguments
    public static RssFragment newInstance(String url) {
        RssFragment newInstance = new RssFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ARG_URL, url);
        newInstance.setArguments(bundle);
        return newInstance;
    }
}
```

ScrollableTabsActivity

```
  public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12847959/rss.xml"), "உலகம்");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12847980/rss.xml"), "சினிமா");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12850122/rss.xml"), "வேலை வாய்ப்பு");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12850077/rss.xml"), "டெக்னாலஜி");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12850128/rss.xml"), "சமையலறை");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12850092/rss.xml"), "விவசாயம்");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12850103/rss.xml"), "கல்வி-வேலைவாய்ப்பு");
        adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12850110/rss.xml"), "விளையாட்டு");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to put an rss feed link to something and get the data.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Could you elaborate a bit more. What `link` are you talking about ? Where is the `silder` in your code ? What do you mean by `come to RSS Slider`. Try editing your post and break it into smaller chunks, explaining what each chunk is and finally what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Nisanth Reddy adapter.addFrag(RssFragment.newInstance("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12847959/rss.xml"), "உலகம்"); I need rss silder to come to me with this link